# I want to make this feature box responsive

Tags: css, wordpress

I created [this](http://bryancollins.eu/wp/) feature box for a WordPress site.

I want to customise the feature box so that the red ribbon to the right of the feature box stays in view as I reduce my screen size.

Also, is it possible to customise this feature box so that it displays in its entirety on smaller mobile screens?

Thanks for the help.

```
   .featured-box {
  border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 1200px; 
}

.featured-box h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;

}

.featured-box p {
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}

.featured-box ul {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.featured-box ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    align: right;
}

.featured-box .enews p {
    padding: 10 10 10 10px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 220 px;
    margin: 10 10 10 10px;

}

.featured-box .enews #subscribe {
    padding: 20 20 20 20px;;

}

.featured-box .enews #subbox {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;

}

.featured-box .enews .myimage {

      float: right;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 50px;
       width: auto;
}

.featured-box .enews input[type="submit"] { 
background-color: #d60000;
     padding: 10 10 10 10px;
     width: 150px;

}



@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1139px) {
    div.featured-box {
        margin-top: 135px;

    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1140px) {
    div.featured-box {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
}


#text-4 > div:nth-child(1) > h4:nth-child(1) {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background-color: #d60000; 
            position: relative;
            margin: 0px -60px 20px -20px;
            padding: 18px 0px 16px 20px;

}

#text-4 > div:nth-child(1) > h4:nth-child(1):after {
                content: '';
                display: block; height: 40px; width: 40px;
                background: url(http://bryancollins.eu/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/fold.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
                position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: -40px;

}

.page p { line-height: 1.2em; }
.page a { color: #1badd2; text-decoration: none; }
.widget li  { 

                margin: 0;  
                padding: 2px 0px 8px 35px; 
                display: block; position: relative; 
                border-bottom: none;

            }


.featured-box .widget li {
                list-style: none;
                background: url("http://bryancollins.eu/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                display: block;
                margin: 0 0 0 30px;
                padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

Comment: Look into "media queries"

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your max-width on .featured-box

Comment: When I do this, the red ribbon doesn't shrink with the feature box as I resize my screen.